# Difference between database level trigger and server level trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please tell me the difference between database level trigger and server level trigger in SQL Server ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 introduced DML Triggers that can be set to fire on your chosen DDL events such as `CREATE_TABLE`, `ALTER_TABLE`, `DROP_TABLE`, `ALTER_DATABASE`, `CREATE_LOGIN` etc.

DDL Triggers can be set within 2 scopes:

1. **Server scope**: Triggers created with Server scope must target server DDL events such as CREATE_DATABASE or CREATE_LOGIN
2. **Database scope**: Triggers created with database scope must target database level events such as CREATE_TABLE or ALTER_PROC.

**See the full list of SQL Server DDL Trigger Events (including their scope) on msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189871.aspx).**

Syntax of a DDL trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TriggerName]
ON [Scope (Server|Database)]
FOR [EventName...],
AS
-- code for your trigger response here
```

Answer (score 0):

**Database trigger** : Database trigger has been work on table like insert, update and delete record.

**Server trigger** : Server trigger has been work on database like drop table and alter table. It is important of security level. If you single user access database should be not important. But Multi user access database has been important. Which user would be work on database.

Refer this link

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/24/sql-server-2005-server-and-database-level-ddl-triggers-examples-and-explanation/

Comment: Could you please provide more information on the same?

Comment: @mukesh Please post it as comment this is not the answer

Comment: Can you provide any examples?

Comment: @leeg4625 refer this link