# what does if we change database to Recursive Triggers Enabled :True?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a feature in sql database to set  Recursive Triggers Enabled, what does this feature will do to the database. In what cases one enable that feature. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SERVER TRIGGER RECURSION` option either allows or disallows for a **server-level** `TRIGGER` to fire another **server-level** `TRIGGER`.

If you have server-level `TRIGGER A` and server-level `TRIGGER B`, and `SERVER TRIGGER RECURSION` is disabled `(0)`, then `TRIGGER A` cannot directly fire `TRIGGER B`.

If the option is enabled, `(1)`, then `TRIGGER A` can fire `TRIGGER B`.

An example would be if you had `TRIGGER A` performing maintenance logic which affected a table where `TRIGGER B` was assigned.  (Again, we're talking server-level, not database level)

Say that `TRIGGER A` updates some value in `TRIGGER B`'s table after some action has been performed.  `TRIGGER B` is supposed to fire whenever a value in its table is updated.  With this option disabled, `TRIGGER B` will not fire.

With the option enabled, `TRIGGER A` will fire first, then `TRIGGER B` will fire after it (assuming that all conditions for the `TRIGGER` to fire are met).

There is also a similar condition for `NESTED TRIGGERS`, which works in a similar way, but at the level of the database rather than the level of the server.

If you don't use server-level triggers, then this option shouldn't concern you.

If you do, I recommend you look over the documentation, and also consider why you actually need them.  There are valid reasons to use them, but generally speaking you can find a better way to get the result that you're after.

There is a good answer on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146754/difference-between-database-level-trigger-and-server-level-trigger-in-sql-server).

**Important:** SQL Server defends itself by implementing a maximum recursion, as Bilal Ayub noted in his response.  If `TRIGGER A` and `TRIGGER B` were to enter a loop - each firing the other in succession - a maximum of 32 attempted transactions would be performed before an error would be thrown and the action canceled.

Answer (score 1):

This means that any trigger can execute another trigger in recursive manner up to maximum 32 times.

Comment: any example you can give here.